# How to handle undefined return from then in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to do some simple stuff.

`func1(x).then(func2)`

I won't use any returned value from `func1` (and yes, in this case `func1` returns `undefined`), and I just want to execute `func2` after `func1`, how am I suppose to do that since `undefined` does not has property `then`?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `func1` asynchronous in any way…?

Comment: func1 has to return a Promise..

Comment: @Keith My question is, what if it cannot return a promise, can we create a default one from the undefined value?

Comment: @deceze yes, it is

Comment: Then it needs to return a promise in some way or accept a callback, otherwise there's no way for you to know when it's finished and you can't execute anything *after* it.

Comment: `what if it cannot return a promise`  You can always return a promise.

Comment: @Keith What if it is from a lib? Can we convert it to promise from the outside?

Comment: @xxx222 — No, because you have no way of knowing when it has finished so you can't tell when to resolve the promise.

Comment: If it's from a lib, then chances are it's either already a Promise, or it uses callbacks that can be made into promises..

Answer (score -1):

Since func1 return type may not be a promise, you have to wrap func1 to a new function that must return a promise.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/kingychiu/gewm60as/

Suppose you have the following function as func1, it returns a promise or undefined based on the bool:

```
function I_will_return_promise_or_undefined(bool){
    if(bool){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve(null);
    });
  }else{
        return undefined
    }
}
```

You can wrap the func1 this way:

```
function wrapper(bool){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var temp = I_will_return_promise_or_undefined(bool);
    if(temp === undefined){
        // resolve it
        resolve(undefined);
    }else{
        // chain promise
        temp.then(function(val){
        resolve(val)
      });
    }
  });
}
```

And finally it is what you want:

```
// null
wrapper(true).then(function(val){
    console.log(true, val);
});

// undefinded
wrapper(false).then(function(val){
    console.log(false, val);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function a(callbackFunction){
   console.log('The first function works');
   collbackFunction();
}
function b(){
   console.log('The second function works');
}
a(b);
```

You will see in console:
'The first function works' and on the new line:
'The second function works'